# How to prevent Google from indexing the /wp-content/ directory?

Tags: robots.txt

I received an error from google saying that I have mobile usability errors on my site.

the "page" that they are referring to is [www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/ag-admin](http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/ag-admin).

I'm not asking for help with that plugin, but trying to figure out how to make google not index that directory at all.

Is disallawing this in my robots.txt enough or should I even have to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the thing

There are multiple ways to do what you want, from adding meta tags, to passing headers, but because, you tagged your question with robots.txt So i consider it off-topic to discuss any other solutions.

Considering your demand you need to have this as your robots.txt
This disallowed access to wp-admin, but depending on use case, you may need ajax, so I gave it an exception, and then disallowed wp-content, and wp-includes.

Change your robots.txt situated in root directory, like this

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Noindex: /wp-content/
Noindex: /wp-includes/
```

This shall ask google to not index anything in wp-content and wp-includes, Google is slow and it would take its bot some time, to realize he is going at wrong place, so it would eventually remove it from its index.

**The below HTACCESS METHOD is completely optional, the Robots.txt can do the trick with work, but HTACCESS is much more consistent method, therefore I couldnt resist myself from telling it**

Incase you are willing to edit ht-access file, then that would be a better approach.

I myself use it on my site. My code below if put in htaccess files, blocks all PHP and backend specific files, but allows all images, videos, pdfs and various similar file formats to be indexed by Google and others.

```
# Serves only static files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^wp-(content|includes)/([^/]+/)*([^/.]+\.)+ (jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|ico|css|js|swf|xml|xsl|html?|mp(eg[34])|avi|wav|og[gv]|xlsx?|docx?|pptx?|gz|zip|rar|pdf|xps|7z|[ot]tf|eot|woff2?|svg|od[tsp]|flv|mov)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-(content|includes|admin/includes)/ - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `robots.txt`**

Yes you could use a `robots.txt` file for this, simply add the following into this file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-content/
```

Notice that you can have multiple `Disallow` directives if you would like to restrict indexing of other folders as well.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
```

If you *would* like to allow indexing on a specific file in the folder you could use an `Allow` directive after `Disallow` like this:

```
Disallow: /wp-content/
Allow: /wp-content/plugins/askimet.php
```

If you only would like to stop google from indexing you could instead add a user agent:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
```

**Using `set Header`**

You should also be able to use `.htaccess` for this. Try adding something like this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
<Directory wp-content>
  Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</Directory>
```

For the above to work you need to have `mod_headers` module enabled in apache. You can enable this module by executing:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Putting `Directory` in `.htaccess` file results in 500 error. :(

Answer (score 0):

**just add this to .htaccess**

```
#Serves only static files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/ - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This id the correct robot.txt

> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /wp-content/
> Disallow: /wp-admin/
> ```